# Advice on Call/Email Log Database software?

Tags: database, logging, reporting

I'm tasked with creating a phone and email logging database for about 30 people in order to collect some mandated statistics on our support.  As an office we need to be able to report how many emails we send and how many/how long we spend on phone support with the public.

At current I'm dabbling with a self-made form that connects with a mysql database, but I need something that's honestly a bit more professional looking, especially as far as generating reports.  I played around with spiceworks, which seems great for a helpdesk environment, but I need something more flexible as far as categorization and user-permissions.  Basically every manager needs to be able to edit the categories specific to their department and run those reports, without me giving them full administrative access over everything.

Everyone is centralized in a single location and the logging software does not need to be accessible outside of the office (so I'm slightly less concerned with security), but optimally there would be some sort of web interface that people can use from their desks to input what issues they've responded to and what/how long they've spent doing so. I do have a budget so I don't necessarily have to have free software, although as always, that'd be great.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a good way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two letters - [rt](http://bestpractical.com/rt/).

you will curse the day when you installed it. you'll curse perl too [ just after you start learning it with rt ]. but it is powerful and flexible. if diving into the code is fine - you can extend it a lot, add custom fields and custom actions. define own workflow etc.

it quite easily integrates with mail system - up to a point that each mail from client can open new issue and can be answered via regular mail client and yet be logged in the system. web gui needs to be used only to assign new ticket / mark it with required attributes and close resolved issue.

issues/events [like phonecall] can be also opened/logged via web gui. it has quite granular permission management, reports [ i think ] can be genrated by anyone who can just read tickets, queries used for them can be saved and used in the future.

aha.. it might not be good looking, report wizard is not easiest tool to use - but it's worth the time spent learning.

Comment: I've spent the last day looking into this.  I can see where the install might be a bit obnoxious, but this looks like a good solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.kubelabs.com/kubesupport/

Comment: Interesting software.  Their admin panel demo didn't work for me.  (wouldn't let me login), but the screenshots seemed useful.  The interface seems  simple and clean, but there is some amount of worry regarding the .9 version and also the extensibility of the software.  That said, thank you for the suggestion.  I looked into it and it might be helpful with another project.